# Firebase Admin SDK not found in Production

Tags: firebase-admin

Am using the firebase SDK to work with my database. In dev mode using localhost everything works fine i can run POST and GET requests and the data runs fine but in Production i get, On the first page load on the home page (which uses a get request), the data loads with no issues but when i go to different page which requires a POST request i get a POST 500 internal server error. Now when i go back to the homepage, i get a GET 500 internal server error. These are my server logs "

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Failed to parse service account json file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path/to/the/sdk.json'
  at ServiceAccount.fromPath (./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:124:19)  
  at new ServiceAccountCredential (./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js:69:28)  
  at cert (./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-factory.js:103:54)  
  at ./chunks/getApparelDesktop.mjs:26:17  
  at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

"

I have moving the file around the app and changing its path but still it works fine in developer mode but throws the 500 internal server error in production